# Using wildcard to Append multiple feature classes in ModelBuilder?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder, arcgis-10.2

I have a folder of shapefiles and each one starts with a code.  There are multiple shapefiles that start with each code, and I would like to create a model in ModelBuilder that will select the shapefiles that have the same code, and append them into the appropriate existing geodatabase feature class.

Is there a way to use a wildcard in the Append tool, like to specify that any and all files in a certain folder starting with 'XPGC*' get appended into the 'Pipe_Grade_Change' feature class?  Or is there a way to use an iterator to accomplish this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would use Iterate Feature Classes and Collect Values as in the graphics below.

[image]

[image]

Comment: This worked for me.  I changed the wildcard in the Iterate tool and the target dataset of the Append tool to model parameters so I can change them when I run the tool.

Comment: After working with this model, I found that it was appending the same feature multiple times.  I was able to fix this problem by removing the Collect Features part of the model.  See this thread for more information: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/73024/using-append-with-wildcard-runs-too-many-times