# Choosing feature classes by wildcard from file geodatabase in ModelBuilder?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder

This must be easy and I have done it a few years ago (I can't recall if it was using a custom python script inside the model) but is there a way to select certain feature classes from a geodatabase to then feed it to another tool (merge in this case)?

I tried Model Only tools - Select Data and Iterators - Feature Classes and Datasets to collect values but it doesn't work...

[image]

So I need to select all the files that have *r_End_* for one merge and *r_Start_* for a seperate merge.

I had a look at [Extracting specific feature class from dataset in ModelBuilder?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/114856/way-to-extract-a-specific-feature-class-from-a-dataset-in-model-builder) and https://geonet.esri.com/thread/102308 as well as the arcmap help.

Comment: What does a test model of just this bit look like?  My first thought is that you might need to use a Python script tool instead of a Model tool.

Comment: thanks. I found http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/72705/how-to-use-wildcard-to-append-multiple-feature-classes-in-modelbuilder?rq=1 and that process worked.